# 3 salesman probability

Tags: probability

Three salesmen a, b, c make house-to-house sales. Their probabilities of making a sale if they all go out for a sales call are $\frac{5}{8}$, $\frac{3}{8}$, and $\frac{1}{3}$.

What is the probability that:

1) a sale will be made

2) only one of the salesmen will make a sale

Comment: it looks like homework, you should tag it as "self-study"

Answer (score 1):

1) First you need to calculate the probability that none of them makes a sale.

$p(\overline{A})p(\overline{B})p(\overline{C}) = (1-5/8)(1-3/8)(1 - 1/3)$ = 0.15625

where for three salesman A, B and C, $p(X)$ is the probability that salesman $X$ sells and $p(\overline{X})$ is the probability that $X$ doesn't sell.

Now the probability of at least one of them selling is equal to $(1 - 0.15625) = 0.84375$

2) There are three scenarios:

$
p({A})p(\overline{B})p(\overline{C}) + p(\overline{A})p({B})p(\overline{C}) + p(\overline{A})p(\overline{B})p({C}) = (5/8)(1-3/8)(1 - 1/3) + (1-5/8)(3/8)(1 - 1/3) + (1-5/8)(1-3/8)(1/3) = 0.260416667 + 0.09375 + 0.078125 = 0.432291667
$

Comment: ... assuming independence, at least

Comment: true, if only assume that a salesman makes a sale is independent from the others